# Elasticsearch: Group by timeframe

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I made this query to get the number of requests a user made in the last month (or day) compared to the rest of the users.

```
{
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": [
            {
                "range": {
                    "created": {
                        "gte": 1554854400000
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
},
"aggs": {
    "requests": {
        "filters": {
            "other_bucket_key": "all",
            "filters": {
                "user": {
                    "match": {
                        "user_id": "XXXXXX"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

These are all the requests made in the selected period of time.
Now, I want to get the number of requests / day the user made in the last month compared to the rest of the users.
I was able to obtain this using Date Histogram Aggregation for the total number of requests made but I can't figure out how to split that into user and the rest.
I don't know if that's possible or maybe there's another way of doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right path, you simply need to combine the `date_histogram` daily aggregation and the filters aggregation you already have:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "created": {
              "gte": 1554854400000
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "per_day": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "created",
        "interval": "day"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "requests": {
          "filters": {
            "other_bucket_key": "all",
            "filters": {
              "user": {
                "match": {
                  "user_id": "XXXXXX"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For each day, you're going to get the number of requests made by the user vs the number of requests for all other users.